# How to increment the value of an object within state React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

So I have this component called counters where the state looks something like this

```html
state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 0 },
      { id: 2, value: 3 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 },
    ],
  };
```

And I'm trying to increment the value every time a corresponding button is clicked. This is the function I wrote for it.

```html
  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
```

It doesn't work. And here are some additional observations.

1. When I console.log the local counters object (copied from state.counters) it returns an additional row at the end with id: -1 and value: NaN
2. The variable counter (thats being passed as a parameter) is from a child component. It's supposed to return 0 if the first button is clicked, 1 if the second button is clicked and so on. When I console.log it it seems to be returning the correct values.

by the looks of it, the problem seems to lie in the line

```html
const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
```

As the value of index is always returned as -1.

Comment: How are you invoking handleIncrement()? What argument are you passing? Can you paste the entire component? If you are passing a reference to a specific counter then indexOf should work, however if you are just passing a key/value, indexOf will not understand.

Comment: Hi @darrendev your question was on point. It's what lead me to discover the issue at hand. While the function on parent side was expecting an object, when invoked on child side it was being given an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the index for updating the corresponding record in the array.

```
const idx = this.state.counters.findIndex((counter) => counter.id === id);
```

Complete implementation:-

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counters: [
        { id: 1, value: 0 },
        { id: 2, value: 3 },
        { id: 3, value: 0 },
        { id: 4, value: 0 }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleClick = (id) => {
    const idx = this.state.counters.findIndex((counter) => counter.id === id);
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    counters[idx] = { ...counters[idx], value: counters[idx].value++ };
    this.setState(counters);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map((counter) => (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(counter.id)}>
              Button {counter.id}
            </button>
            <span>Value {counter.value}</span>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-black-cippbs?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

try this for get the index:

```
const index = counters.findIndex(x => x.id === counter.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer here just in case another confused soul stumbles upon it.

Although it seemed that the problem lied within line

```
const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
```

It actually was in the child component where the function was being invoked. Within the parameter I was passing counters.value whereas the handleincrement function within the parent component was expecting not the value, rather the complete object.

The code in its working condition is as below
Parent Component:

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 0 },
      { id: 2, value: 3 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 },
    ],
  };
  
  
    handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    console.log(index);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
```

Child Component:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {

render() {
    return (
<button
          onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        
        )
        }
        
        
]
```